# Change Owl Carousel Slide on hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel and I want to change the slide on hover of a custom set of owl dots. I've added code that adds click functionality to the dots on hover but all that does is disable the click functionality for those dots that I've added it to.

PHP

```
<?php if(have_rows('apt_section_4')):
while(have_rows('apt_section_4')) : the_row();
    $heading = get_sub_field('heading');
    $paragraph = get_sub_field('paragraph');
    $slide_image_bathroom = get_sub_field('slide_image_bathroom');
    $slide_image_heating = get_sub_field('slide_image_heating');
    $slide_image_kitchen = get_sub_field('slide_image_kitchen');
    $slide_image_utility = get_sub_field('slide_image_utility');
    $slide_image_ensuites = get_sub_field('slide_image_ensuites');
    $slide_image_balcony = get_sub_field('slide_image_balcony');





endwhile; ?>

<section class="hover-gallery-section">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="gallery-container">
            <div class=" gsap-fade-in-up">
                <ul id='hover-carousel-custom-dots-1' class='nav-owl owl-dots-1' data-slide="1">
                    <li class="hover-owl-dot-1"><h3>SLEEK BATHROOM</h3></li>
                    <li class="hover-owl-dot-1"><h3>INTELLIGENT HEATING SYSTEM</h3></li>
                    <li class="owl-dot-1"><h3>HOTPOINT APPLIANCES IN THE KITCHEN</h3></li>
                    <li class="owl-dot-1"><h3>UTILITY SPACES</h3></li>
                    <li class="owl-dot-1"><h3>ENSUITES</h3></li>
                    <li class="owl-dot-1"><h3>BALCONY</h3></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- .top-navigation -->
            <div class="row gsap-fade-in-up">
                <div class="col col-1">
                    <div class="main-slide active opacity" data-slide="1">
                        <div id="slider-hover-gallery" class="slider-hover-gallery owl-carousel owl-theme chocolat-parent">
                            <div class="slide">
                                <?php /* <p class="tagline"></p> */ ?>


                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $slide_image_bathroom['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide_image_bathroom['alt']; ?>" />

                                <?php /*
                            <a class="chocolat-image" href="<?php echo $one_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $one_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>">
                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $one_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $one_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>" />
                            </a> */ ?>
                            </div> <!-- .slide -->
                            <div class="slide">
                                <?php /* <p class="tagline"></p> */ ?>

                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $slide_image_heating['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide_image_heating['alt']; ?>" />
                                <?php /*
                            <a class="chocolat-image" href="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>">
                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>" />
                            </a> */?>
                            </div> <!-- .slide -->
                            <div class="slide">
                                <?php /* <p class="tagline"></p> */ ?>

                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $slide_image_kitchen['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide_image_kitchen['alt']; ?>" />
                                <?php /*
                            <a class="chocolat-image" href="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>">
                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>" />
                            </a> */?>
                            </div> <!-- .slide --> <div class="slide">
                                <?php /* <p class="tagline"></p> */ ?>

                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $slide_image_utility['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide_image_utility['alt']; ?>" />
                                <?php /*
                            <a class="chocolat-image" href="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>">
                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>" />
                            </a> */?>
                            </div> <!-- .slide --> <div class="slide">
                                <?php /* <p class="tagline"></p> */ ?>

                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $slide_image_ensuites['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide_image_ensuites['alt']; ?>" />
                                <?php /*
                            <a class="chocolat-image" href="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>">
                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>" />
                            </a> */?>
                            </div> <!-- .slide --> <div class="slide">
                                <?php /* <p class="tagline"></p> */ ?>

                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $slide_image_balcony['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide_image_balcony['alt']; ?>" />
                                <?php /*
                            <a class="chocolat-image" href="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>">
                                <img class="no-lazy" src="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $two_bedroom_floorplan['alt']; ?>" />
                            </a> */?>
                            </div> <!-- .slide -->

                        </div> <!-- .floorplan-slider -->
                    </div> <!-- .main-slide -->


                </div> <!-- .col-1 -->

            </div> <!-- .row -->
        </div>


    </div> <!-- .container -->
</section> <!-- .explore-apartments-section -->
```

Here's the JS with the slider and custom dot functionality.

```
 $(function(){
    owl = $('#slider-hover-gallery')
    owl.owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        loop:false,
        autoplay:false,
        margin:0,
        nav:false,
        dots:true,
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        dotsContainer: '#hover-carousel-custom-dots-1',
    });
});

 $('.owl-dot-1').click(function () {
    $('#slider-floorplans').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
    $('#slider-gallery').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
    $('#slider-virtual').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
    $('#slider-hover-gallery').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);


});

$('.hover-owl-dot-1').hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
}, function() {});
```